# How to get text font in pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i am using itextsharp
and i am trying to get all the fonts of the given string in pdf file
is this possible
if it can be done in any language i please tell me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [iTextSharp Tutorial](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch09.html)

Comment: the tutorial is about making pdf documents what i want to do is to read pdf document and get font for certain word in that pdf lets say i search for "Adnan" and i get all the reference for "Adnan" but i also want to know the fonts used thanks –